# Looking for recomendation to show release notes in ClickOnce applications

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have a few strategies which I'm about to trial in a few scenarios and am looking for guidance on what others have had experience with and proven successful.

The current strategies I have in mind are:

- Place a release-notes.xml file in the root of the publish location which contains formatted notes that the application can manually download when it detects a new version available.
- Use a `FileGroup` and download that group using `ApplicationDeployment.DownloadFileGroup(String)` which would contain the said release notes.

I only want the release notes prior an update. I'm handling application updates myself through `ApplicationDeployment.CheckForUpdateAsync` and notifying the user through the application status bar and was thinking of allowing them to view what has changed prior to initiating the application update.

Any other suggestions are very much welcome.

I should make it clear that the use case for the release notes are prior to an update to allow the user to determine if they should choose to update at that time or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are suggesting sounds plausible. However, I would try keep it as simple as possible...

- An [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) file of the release notes published to your web server.
- Show the users the release notes through their browser...
  `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(relaseNotesUrl);`

Comment: In essence this would be a good simple solution, however we have a policy with our apps to not open other applications as it confuses end users. We are not allowed to start web browser processes or acrobat etc.

Comment: Gotta love random policies. I would argue that a user reading release notes probably isn't confused by a browser window, but that's just my take. There's nothing wrong with the methods you suggested - just a little more work.

Comment: If you're deploying a Windows Forms application, and if you're handling updates programmatically, so that you're inside the application already, why can't you open a form with a WebBrowser object within it pointing at said HTML file?  That would not qualify as "opening other applications", I would think.  (I imagine there's a similar solution in WPF -- this just happens to be the solution I'm familiar with).

Comment: No clean solution in WPF without using the embedded webform from Windows Forms. It amazes me that WPF does not yet have a browser component.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with codeConcussion. You can also use ApplicationDeployment.IsFirstRun to tell if the user has installed a new version. It's true after an update or after the 1st installation. But since you're doing the updates programmatically, you can probably just pop up the web browser at that point.

Comment: The release notes are required prior performing an update, not after. The point is to have an icon appear in the status bar of the application alerting there is an update available, clicking that icon allows the user to see what was updated and choose to update at that point or not.