# How to provide description of update with ClickOnce?

Tags: c#, clickonce, updates

We have an app which I've coded up and for ages now I've pushed updates to it through ClickOnce.  The app sits on our main file server.  But every time I push out an update I get asked what I've changed!  Is there any way to provide a personalised description of an update with ClickOnce which would be user-friendly?  For example, when the user launches their application, ClickOnce asks "A new version is available.  Would you like to update?", below which I could have a description of what I've updated?  Or is this impossible with ClickOnce?

Comment: Just introduce a form when the program is launched that displays this information.  ClickOnce does not support doing something like this though.

Comment: I like your idea there.  I'd just need to program it so it only shows up the once I guess, or give the user the option to get rid of it on subsequent starts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's how I do it.  I call this method in my startup code, in Release mode:

```
using System.Deployment.Application;
...

private void DisplayChangeLog()
{
    if (!ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
        return;

    if (!ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun)
        return;

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
        Execute.OnUIThread(() => <Pop up window with latest changes> ));
}
```

I know this isn't **precisely** what you want, as it displays the first time the user runs the app but **after** they've already installed the update.  In our environment users don't have a choice whether they update or not, so it makes no real difference.

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to do with ClickOnce as standard. If you want to show the user a message about changes then you will need to implement it yourself. One way to do this is to diable automatic updating and then [check for updates programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx). You can then use the version to get the change from say an XML file or similar and show it to the user.

Alternatively, you could just provide a [changelog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changelog) in HTML format or something which is likely a lot simpler.

For example, see Stack Overflow question *[Looking for recomendation to show release notes in ClickOnce applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871144)*.

Either way, in general if there is an update, why would the user not want it?

Comment: "Either way, in general if there is an update why would the user not want it?" - My users are very pessimistic creatures unfortunately :)!  Thanks for your comment, it certainly looks to be more difficult than I would have expected, so I think I'll go down the route of your recommendation for doing a changelog in HTML format or something similar.  Thanks again!

Comment: It isn't that difficult to achieve with manual updates. I have done it myself to automatically update in the background (amongst other things). It's worth learning if you are planning to use ClickOnce a lot in the future. It does add a LOt more flexibilty and would enable you to show only the updates since the currently installed version etc. without having to open external files. Can certainly recommend some further investigation (MSDN is helpful here).

Comment: I will review the links and go from there I think.  Thanks to everyone for your input.

Comment: Oh yes, one thing I forgot to mention that throws a spanner into the works. If you were needing to provide this info before the user updates they would need access to the changelog so it would have to be accessible by the application wherever it is e.g webserver or network share (depends on where your app is deployed).

Comment: It is more intended as a tool to inform the user what has been changed after the update goes through.  Otherwise I have about 10 people asking me the same question in one day, when all I've done most of the time is fixed a typo in the GUI or something!

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured. In which case it's very easy to provide a html page which is included in the deployment which users can view whenever they like. It would be simple enough to keep the currrent version number stored somewhere, and if it has been incremented automatically show the changelog (as suggested by ramhound) and then save the new version number.

Answer (score 2):

I have spent a considerable amount of time in the recent past studying and programmatically manipulating the manifest files that are produced during the publishing of a ClickOnce application and I've not seen a way to add a free form description like the one you want, and there certainly isn't a way to achieve it via the wizard or UI provided by Visual Studio.

(Caveat: I'll double check this tomorrow at work just to make sure there is absolutely no way at all - but you should assume that there isn't.)

Comment: That's good to know, I thought I had been missing something really obvious!

Comment: As I said, I am almost certain you can't do it like this and it would likely be more work if it was possible. If you have to fiddle around each time modyfying external files etc it become a pain. I would favour a simple xml file with change decription and version number and then using the API to check for updates and display all changes that have been made between current version and new version.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the update dialog for ClickOnce as long as you let ClickOnce check for updates automatically.

To achieve this, you would have to handle updates programmatically in your application using the methods provided by `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment`. This allows you to define your own update dialog. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx) for the official HowTo. The core principle is the following:

```
ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
info = ad.CheckForDetailedUpdate();
if (info.UpdateAvailable)
{
    // insert your update dialog here
    ad.Update();
}
```

However, there used to be a bug within the approach described in there when calling `ad.Update()` and you have file associations in your ClickOnce deployment. See the [forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c1c03973-7247-49ed-9eeb-cd9c83067e8b/clickonce-application-update-throw-exception-about-fileassociation?forum=winformssetup&forum=winformssetup) and [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/612125/updateasync-on-clickonce-deployment-with-file-associations-causes-nullreferenceexception) for more info. (I don't know if the bug has been fixed.)

As a workaround for this, you could replace `ad.Update()` by these lines:

```
var application = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdatedApplicationFullName.Split('#')[0] + "?";
proc = new Process { StartInfo = { FileName = "iexplore.exe", Arguments = application, UseShellExecute = true } };
proc.Start();
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```